# Dynamically including/excluding DataGrid in layout in flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am using DataGrid which is visible when its dataprovider has records.
User can add/remove rows from dataProvider on runtime.
Grid should only be included in layout when it has some records otherwise not.

I use includeInLayout and visible properties of DataGrid to handle this, but it doesnot assign proper width to columns once it gets out of layout and include again

I am setting includeInLayout true/false in each row add/delete and setting columns width dynamically in commitProperties

Please anyone help me out!

Answer (score 0):

To add/remove rows from `DataGrid` you shouldn't perform any operations with `DataGrig` rows themselves (I'm just curious how do you perform it :). You should add/remove rows adding/removing data provider items. And then put the following declaration to `DataGrid`:

```
<mx:DataGrid includeInLayout="{dataProvider.length > 0}" 
    visible="{dataProvider.length > 0}" />
```

Comment: by adding rows in grid, I meant exactly what you said, by adding items in grid, and I set includeInLayout and visible exactly the way you said. but it do something wrong with the width of the columns. I have five colmuns, each assigned fixed width , but it only shows two columns

Comment: Maybe these widths are too wide?